# article, twocolumn with centered (horizontally) spanning abstract

Tags: html

I'm using the twocolumn layout with article. I would like to have my abstract span the two columns (after title and authors, but before the first section). Is this possible?

Comment: It depends on your HTML, can you post your mark-up?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to post this to the tex.stackoverflow. I'm using latex.

Comment: I posted in tex and also found the answer! http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28109/how-can-i-place-a-one-column-abstract-in-a-two-column-document